# How to resolve java : not found?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, environment-variables, cassandra

I execute the command `sudo cassandra -R` to start `cassandra` and I get the following error.

```
getopt: invalid option -- 'R'
/usr/sbin/cassandra: 158: exec: java: not found
```

It points to the following line in the cassandra script.

```
else
        exec $NUMACTL "$JAVA" $JVM_OPTS $cassandra_parms -cp "$CLASSPATH"
```

Is it because the environment variable `JAVA` is not set?
If yes, how to set the variable?

The output of `echo $JAVA_HOME` is blank. This is the output of `java -version`:

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Well *is* `$JAVA` set? Please [edit] and provide the output of `echo $JAVA` and `java -version`.

Comment: Please run `JAVA=$(which java) && sudo cassandra` – let’s see whether it’s as simple as that. :)

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions for cassandra at http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for that is to set `JAVA_HOME` variable to point to your java installation. The cassandra script should generally autodeetect your java location on `PATH`, but if it doesn't happen, you can help with setting `JAVA_HOME` explicitly:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/
```

Note: you must set `JAVA_HOME` not `JAVA`. `JAVA` variable is used internally by the cassandra launch scripts, but you're not supposed to set it. `JAVA` is set  by this code snippet in `cassandra.in.sh`:

```bsh
# Use JAVA_HOME if set, otherwise look for java in PATH
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
    # Why we can't have nice things: Solaris combines x86 and x86_64
    # installations in the same tree, using an unconventional path for the
    # 64bit JVM.  Since we prefer 64bit, search the alternate path first,
    # (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4638).
    for java in "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/amd64/java "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java; do
        if [ -x "$java" ]; then
            JAVA="$java"
            break
        fi
    done
else
    JAVA=`command -v java 2> /dev/null`
fi
```